# Cassandra performance on querying fewer or more nodes

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

Consider a growing number of data, let's choose from two extreme choices:

1. Evenly distribute all data across **all** nodes in the cluster
2. We pack them to as **few** nodes as possible

I prefer option 1 because as the volume of data grows, we can scatter it with all nodes, so that when each node is queried, it has the lowest load.

However, some resources state that we shouldn't query all the nodes because that will slow down the query. Why would that slow the query?  Isn't that just a normal scatter and gather?  They even claim this hurts linear scalability as adding more nodes will further drag down the query.
(Maybe I am missing on how Cassandra performs the query, some background reference is appreciated).

On the contrary, some resources state that we should go with option 2 because it queries the least number of nodes.

Of course there is no black and white choices here; everything must have a tradeoff.

I want to know, what's the real difference between option 1 and option 2.  Plus, regarding the network querying, why option 1 would be slow.

Comment: I recommend to read first chapters of this book to understand how Cassandra works & how to model table structure for it: https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide

Answer (score 1):

> I prefer option 1 because as the volume of data grows, we can scatter it with all nodes, so that when each node is queried, it has the lowest load.

You definitely want to go with option #1.  This is also preferable, in that new or replacement nodes will stream *much* faster than a cluster made of fewer, dense nodes.

> However, some resources state that we shouldn't query all the nodes because that will slow down the query.

And those resources are *absolutely* correct.  First of all, if you read through the resources which Alex posted above you'll discover how to build your tables so that your queries can be served by a single node.  Running queries which only hit a single node is the best way around that problem.

> Why would that slow the query?

Because in a distributed database environment, query time becomes network time.  There are many people out there who like to run multi-key or unbound queries against Cassandra.  When that happens, and the query is unable to find a single node with the data, Cassandra picks one node to designate as a "coordinator."

That node builds the result set with data from the other nodes.  Which means in a 30 node cluster, that one node is now pulling data from the other 29.  Assuming that these requests don't time-out, the likelihood that the coordinator will crash due to trying to manage too much data is very high.

The bottom line, is that this is one of those tradeoffs between a CA relational database and an AP partitioned row store.  Build your tables to support your queries, store data together which is queried together, and Cassandra will perform just fine.